# How Do SPViewScope Enum Members Map to CAML Scope Options?

Tags: csom, caml

The SharePoint CSOM library defines an enum named SPViewScope with the members Default, Recursive, RecursiveAll, and FilesOnly.

The CAML specification defines the Scope attribute of the  element as being able to have the following values: All, RecursiveAll, and Recursive.

How are the Default and FilesOnly members of the enum represented in CAML? And what enum member corresponds to the CAML Scope 'All'?